# Saving page state to current route as parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Any clue on how to keep sincronized some information about the state of a particular page directly in the url as a url parameter.

Considering this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aegabnxooly?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

I would like that every time the food is selected the url is updated with  param `?favouriteFood=selectedFood`

Of course such params, if present, will be used on the ngInit() to initialize the state of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztm9ti?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts).

Here are the key steps:

1. Import the Angular [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) into your app:

   ```
   @NgModule({
     imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([])
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
   ```
2. Listen to route query parameter changes from the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute):

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
      // Remember to unsubscribe when this component is destroyed
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        const selectedFood = this.foods.find(f => f.value === params.food);
        if (selectedFood) {
          this.selectedFood = selectedFood;
        }
     });
   }
   ```
3. Update the URL when the user changes the selection from the available choices using [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate):

   ```
   foodSelectionChange(change: MatSelectChange) {
     const food: Food = change.value;
     this.router.navigate([], { 
       queryParams: { food: food.value }
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly whai i was looking for.
Here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztm9ti-v2m4x5 your example with the unsubscription implemented

Answer (score 0):

Try using `replaceState`.

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent
{
  constructor( private location: Location )
  {}

  setTheFood()
  {    
    this.location.replaceState('favouriteFood=selectedFood');
  }
}
```